# how to purge messages from Q? Could a message could be subscribed by 2 times?

Tags: java, jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue

Now I'm working at a MQ product which is fitting J2EE standard.  I can access this Queue via Java client application or J2EE beans.
I'm using this queue by the mode of topic/subscribe.
Let's have the twitter as an example:

Q1:   User always send message to this Q.  So that Q will become very huge.  Do you have good solution to purge some overtime messages from Q to database?  If so, do this solution fit to J2EE standard? or it's some product related featured solution?
Q2:  A scenario:  The first day, user1 send 10 messages to this Q. Then user2 subscribed these 10 message from Q to his local.  The second day,  user2 delete his local 10 messages.  The 3rd day, user1 send 5 new messages to this Q.  Then user2 subscribed this topic on this 3rd day.
Now what does user2 get?  User2 get 5 new messages?  or user2 get 5 new messages and 10 old messages together?
If user2 get 5 new messages, do you have good solution to let user2 always get all of 15 messages (5 new messages and 10 old messages)?
Can user2 get the new message by some condition? like by time condition, users2 only get messages after some time point. 
like by sequence condition, user2 only get the latest 100 messages, no matter whether or not these 100 messages had been subscribed by him

It's just my questions.

Comment: You question is very confusing but I suggest you look at having individual expiry for messages by setting the TTL to a specific value.  That way the msgs will be automatically removed from the queue once they are no longer relevant

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. Do you have some solution to let the removed messages from queue to DB?

Comment: I am still unclear on exactly what you want to do, you should probably edit your question.  Regardless you probably want a dead letter queue that you can then read from and import all expired messages into a DB